# What direction of force on the conductor in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic

The question:

[image]

The answer:

[image]

In my opinion the force should be UP!

Source:

PPI PE Power Practice Problems, 4th Edition – Over 400 Electrical Engineering Practice Problems for the NCEES PE Electrical Power Exam

John A. Camara PE

Publisher ‏ : ‎ PPI a Kaplan Company; Revised, Fourth Edition, Revised (March 10, 2021)

ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1591267862

ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1591267867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don‘t know what type of hand you have, but with my right hand it goes like this:

Current: Index finger pointing into the paper. Mag. field: Middle finger pointing right. Force: Thumb pointing down.

Comment: The "corkscrew rule" ... not "better" ?   :)